# Jmeter doesn't save response data or headers

Tags: save, load, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm building some simple load testing for my API, and to make sure everything is on the up and up I'd like to also review the response headers and data. But when I run my test using the command line and then re-open the GUI to add a View Results Tree listener and load the created file the response headers or response data is empty.

I entered the following values into user.properties (also tried uncommenting those values in jmeter.properties and changing them there, same result)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv (tried xml, omitting it, jtl)
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

But still no luck when opening the result file. I tried declaring the file after the -l tag as results.csv, .jtl, even .xml but none of them show me the headers and data.

I'm running it locally on Mac OS X 10.10 using the following command, jmeter version is 2.12

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t /Users/[username]/Documents/API_test.jmx -l results_15.jtl
```

I don't know if it's not even saving that data, or if the Listeners can't read it or if I've been cursed but any help is appreciated.

It works fine if I add a Listener and run it using the GUI, but if I try to run my larger tests that way, well, things don't end well for anyone.

So my question is: 
**How do I save the response header and data to a file when using the command line, and how do I then view said file in jmeter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Simple Data Writer (under Listeners) and output to a file (NB: different file than your log). Under the 'configure' button, there are all sorts of options of what to save. One of the check boxes is Save Response Header.

This file can get huge if you're saving a bunch of things for every request- one strategy is to check everything, but only save for errors. But you can do whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn on "Functional Test Mode" which will produce a large file but will contain pretty much anything you might need to debug your test.

Beware, this can create a very large JTL file, so don't forget to turn it off for your large test runs! See [JMeter Maven mojo throws IllegalArgumentException with large JTL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865446/jmeter-maven-mojo-throws-illegalargumentexception-with-large-jtl-file)

Alternatively use a Tree View Listener in the GUI for a small sample of the requests and check the request/response in the GUI (including headers) to debug or check your test.

Answer (score 1):

Add Below lines in **user.properties** file

jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml

jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true

Restart cmd prompt.